# Importing services in the Grails console?

Tags: grails, grails-web-console

How do I get the services in the grails console? My business rules are implemented in services but I don't have access to them in the grails console. Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Do you mean the graphical Groovy console you get when you run `grails console`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Spring `ApplicationContext` is available as the `ctx` variable in the console, and you can use this to access Spring beans such as services. Typically that would be `def myService = ctx.getBean('myService')` but Grails adds a metaclass helper so you can just do `def myService = ctx.myService`

Comment: Burt Beckwith

Thank you for your help!