# Can I use the GrailsSwingConsole App to test a service?

Tags: grails

My app is very large and startup times are long! In IntelliJ I get the spinning cursor frequently in OS X. To test small parts of my app can I create/inject a service and call it's function/methods from the Grails Swing Console app. I can fetch domain objects from Grails Swing Console but can't get services to work. If I define the service it's not initialized/injected. I also tried def fooService = new fooService() but I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

```
void fooTest() {

  Foo.withNewSession { session ->
    def fooService = new FooService()

    if (fooService) {
      fooService.initFooCache()
      log.info("Foo Service is initialized!")
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Yes, you can get a service from the Grails console. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733609/importing-services-in-the-grails-console

Comment: I think it would be in appropriate to make this kind of change to someone else's question so I won't edit it myself, but the first 2 sentences of your question are superfluous noise that don't contribute to clarifying your question.  Eliminating those will improve the quality of your question.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on specifically what you are trying to test, you probably want to retrieve the service instance from the Spring application context using something like `ctx.getBean('bean name goes here')`.